# how to assign a data-attribute value to a php variable on click

Tags: php, yii2

this is my html code

```
<li><a class="link_class" data-id="1" data-tab="historical-data">Historical</a></li>
```

I want to assign the above data-tab attribute value to a php variable and then use this in a query. data-tab attribute is changing dynamically on click.
for example `$data_tab = historical-data;` and then us it in the query.

This is my Yii code

```
$all_variables = DefVariables::find()->where(['data_tabs'=> $data_tab])->asArray()->all();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: so you are trying to send `data-tab` value through ajax? Or normal form submit? Because saving that value in variable will not serve any purpose

Comment: actually i want to populate the data in a drop down list on clicking several links having different `data-tab` values so on each click different data should be populated in drop down list regarding with `data-tab`

Comment: You need to use ajax. Populate dropdown data using ajax request.